# Making a getAsText() with Date in PropertyEditorSupport and @Initbinder

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, propertyeditor, spring-mvc-initbinders

I need to convert date with pattern "yyyy-MM-dd" to String format "dd.MM.yyyy". Now i have this. Method getAsText() doesn't work meanwhile setAsText working. What i do wrong?

DateEditor.java

```
@Component
public class DateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String value) {
        try {
            setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(value));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            setValue(null);
        }
    }

     @Override
    public String getAsText() {

        String sdf = "";

        try {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            dateFormat.setLenient(true);//-

            Date date = dateFormat.parse((String) getValue());
            sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(date);

            System.out.println(sdf);
        } catch (ParseException p) {}

        return sdf;
    }

}
```

Initbinder

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
         dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,new DateEditor());
}
```

Comment: Define how is it "not working". I can think of several ways this might be broken, and I don't want to list them all.

Comment: It's just printing the first date format, but not converting. p.printStackTrace(); show nothing

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: It is probably not execute this method, but why?

Comment: Would it be possible that you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with clear statement of expected result, observed result and how they differ? I think it would greatly help answering the question.

Comment: Date in db -> 1966-10-12. Expectation result = 12.10.1966

Comment: Debug shows the correct "return" value but, in form i have the old one